# how to $set Data in mongodb update

Tags: mongodb

Below is the data fields i have in my collection.

```
  { "_id" : "TLa7L9HJTabD6ooLJ", "userId" : "dgS4gJtoEPoRrGE2b", "data" : { "contact" : [ "firstname", "lastname", "phone", "email", "leadsource" ] } }
```

i am try to replace `data.contact` array value with new array i am using this query

```
setting.update({
                _id: doc.userId
            }, {
                $set: {
                    "data.contact":["data1","data2"]
                }
            },function(error){
                if(error){
                    console.log(error.reason);
                }else{
                    toastr.success('User Details updated.');
                }
            });
```

Once my above query run i got success message but in Database this value

`"data.contact":["data1","data2"]`  still not updated.

Comment: How do you check the value in the database after the query to know whether it has been updated or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you are not mistaken in this line:

```
{
    _id: doc.userId
}
```

shouldn't it be:

```
{
    userId: doc.userId
}
```

because you have such field in database. Maybe it's just a simple mistake.